# Apply rounded border as well as shadow doesn't work for UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uitextfield

I want to achieve the following UI
[image]

And here is my code for it

```
class RoundTextField: UITextField {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        customize()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        customize()
    }

    func customize() {
        apply(shadow: true)
    }

    func apply(shadow: Bool) {
        if shadow {
            borderStyle = .none
            layer.cornerRadius = bounds.height / 2

            layer.borderWidth = 1.0
            layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
            layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 5.0)
            layer.shadowRadius = 2
            layer.masksToBounds = false
            layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
        } else {

        }
    }
}
```

And here is the issue detail,

- Case 1: For the above code I get a textField without any border or shadow,
- Case 2: If I comment the first two lines, I get the shadow effect with the border is not rounded, and the border gets to default rounded border.

> ```
> borderStyle = .none
> layer.cornerRadius = bounds.height / 2
> ```

How could I resolve this issue ?

Comment: `borderStyle = .none` You're telling you're textField to not show a border. Try `.line` or `.bezel` or `.roundedRect`

Comment: Where did you call your customize() method?

Comment: I doubt you will get this appearance with a `UITextField` alone. More likely you will need to create a `UIView` subclass that sets the border, rounded corners and shadow, and has a `UITextField` subview.

Comment: @Magnas: Ya tried that too but no rounded corners :-(

Comment: @MikeQiu: Sorry for not updating the complete code, I have updated the code, I hope you got your answer there.

Comment: @DonMag: Ya I thought of that, But my situation is like I have used it textField in most of my screens, So I thought I might get any idea to get it done with the TextField itself :-(. I think you get my situation right :-)

Comment: @DonMag: I also found by trying that I cant have both rounded TextField and shadow together by making use of same layer of the textField, So I have also tried to add one more layer with shadow effect alone, but it has no effects too :-(

Comment: @Bharath: Hi, Bharath, I delete the super.customize() because it will cause error and I can see border and shadow by your code, the case 1 is not happening on my side. I don't know why.

Comment: @MikeQiu: Actually that super.customize() is not applicable here my actual code has another common base class but dummy customize method, I have removed it. And Do you get the rounder border as well as the shadow effect ? Thats great, could you please share the code in Answer section, I wana checkout what I have missed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't reproduce the case 1 you encounter so I will post my code that seems achieve the UI you want.

```
class RoundTextField: UITextField {

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        borderStyle = .none
        layer.cornerRadius = bounds.height / 2
        layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.init(colorLiteralRed: 241/256, green: 241/256, blue: 241/256, alpha: 1).cgColor
        layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1.0)
        layer.shadowRadius = 2
        layer.masksToBounds = false
        layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
        // set backgroundColor in order to cover the shadow inside the bounds
        layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    }
}
```

This is the screenshot of my simulator:
[image]

Comment: This code worked fine, It seems shadow related properties need to be applied in layoutSubviews(), I will analyse why this happens further, Thank you.

Comment: @Bharath, you're welcome, I put my code in layoutSubviews() because I need to use bounds.height to determine the cornerRadius, and layoutSubviews() is where autolayout implemented behind the screens.

Comment: If the height is fixed, I think you needn't put these shadow specific code in layoutSubviews().

Answer (score 1):

You should set **layer.masksToBounds** to true.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling these method from LayoutSubViews instead.

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        // Call here
    }
```